# Show an event belongs to sigma-algebra generated by a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

This is exercise 1.7 of Karatz and Shreve, and I'm not sure how to start. I would be grateful if anyone could talk through this problem (and also a general thinking process for solving stochastic process problem in general):

---

Let $X$ be a stochastic process, every sample path of which is cad-lag. Let A be the event that $X$ is continuous on $[0, t_0)$. Show that $A \in \mathcal{F}_{t_o}^X$.

---

I am having a lot of trouble doing this - a bit discouraging as it is one of the first exercises in the book.

I see a solution in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333458/filtration-exercise, but honestly I am unable to understand it and am looking for something different/simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{s,t \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,t_0-\frac 1  k], |s-t| <\frac 1 n}\{|X_t-X_s| <\frac 1 m\}$.

[For $\subseteq$ use uniform continuity on $[0,t_0-\frac  1 k]$. For the reverse inclusion use right continuity of paths].